# Finding the covariance when given joint pdf

Tags: probability, covariance

If the joint probability density of X and Y given by

$$
  f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
1/4(2x+y),  & 0<x<1, 0<y<1\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

Can I get some hints on how to find the Cov(x,y)?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we could just consider the question through the relationship between marginal distribution and joint distribution.

The marginal probability density of y is $f_Y(y)=\int_0^1f(x,y)dx$=1/4(1+y),

so $E(Y)=\int_0^1yf_Y(y)dy=5/24$

then just calculate $E(X)$ and $E(XY)=\int_0^1\int_0^1xyf(x,y)dydx$.

Answer (score 1):

**Outline:** We want to calculate $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$.  The three expectations can each be found by evaluating the appropriate double integral.

Comment: This is where I'm having issues. I started by calculating the E(x) = $\int_0^1 \frac14(2x+y)dx$. However, I know this is not correct because my answer is in terms of y. I believe E(XY) = $\int_0^1 \int_0^2 \frac14(2x+y)dx$

Comment: @Ayoshna Use $\mathsf E[g(X,Y)] = \int_0^1\int_0^2 g(x,y) f(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x$.

Comment: Okay so when I want e(x) i use the x bounds for both x and y. And then for e(y) I use the y bounds for both x and y. And then for e(xy) I use the respective bounds for x and y??

Comment: No, you use the same bounds for the double integrals; you just change the expected function, $g(\bullet,\bullet)$:   $\begin{align}\mathsf E[X] & = \int_0^1\int_0^2 x\, f(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x \\ \mathsf E[Y] & = \int_0^1\int_0^2 y\, f(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x \\ \mathsf E[XY] & = \int_0^1\int_0^2 xy\, f(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\end{align}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Thank you for clearly telling OP how to calculate. W